# Совмещение класса, переменных медиа-запроса

Tags: css

Задача задать переменную в root для определенного класса еще и с учетом @media. То есть нужно примерно так:

```
@media {
:root {
.class * {
--переменная; 
}
}
}
```

Или так:

```
@media {
.class * {
:root {
--переменная; 
}
}
}
```

В каком варианте вложенность сработает. И возможно ли так вообще?

Comment: `в root для определенного класса` "для определенного класса" задавать в root в принципе бессмысленно. прямо в классе и задавайте переменную. либо если она нужна вне этого класса, можно попробовать что то такое: `input#abc:checked ~ *{--var: 123;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исходя из ваших предположений, правильная иерархия будет

```
@media {
  :root selector {
    --variables: value;
  }
}
```

```css
:root {
  --size: 100px;
}

body {display: flex; gap: 5px;}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.small-box {
  display: block;
  width: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  height: calc(var(--size) / 2);
}

.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   :root .blue {
    --size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">
  <div class="small-box purple"></div>
</div>
<div class="box blue">
  <div class="small-box green"></div>
</div>
```

Но смысла писать `:root` я лично не вижу, ибо если мы переназначим переменную в определённом классе, то дальше по вложенности будет использоваться уже изменённая переменная.

```css
:root {
  --size: 100px;
}

body {display: flex; gap: 5px;}

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.small-box {
  display: block;
  width: calc(var(--size) / 2);
  height: calc(var(--size) / 2);
}

.red {
  background-color: #f00;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #00f;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #800080;
}

.green {
  background-color: #008000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .blue {
    --size: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box red">
  <div class="small-box purple"></div>
</div>
<div class="box blue">
  <div class="small-box green"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Оба варианта не работают. Возможно, не там ищу ответ. Изначально в root задан глобальный множитель для шрифтов (также заданы глобально в виде переменных вroot). Множитель нужен для увеличения шрифтов в гаджетах, исключив шапку и футер сайта.

Comment: Оба варианта работают, это видно в сниппетах, скорее всего в вашем используемом коде либо неверный подход изначально, либо после. В любом случае решение проще получить, если вы добавите в свой вопрос минимальный код из используемого кода и вот на основе него, вы уже получится более верный ответ.